# Uniform continuity of sequence of functions on two different sets

Tags: analysis

Let $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly to $f$ on a set $A$ and on a set $B$, separately. Is it true that the sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly to $f$ on the set $A\cup B$ ?
Can anybody have an answer, or counter-example, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assum $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $A$ and on $B$.
Then given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_A$ with $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in A$ and $n>n_A$.
And there exists $n_B$ with $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in B$ and $n>n_B$.
Then for all $n>\max\{n_A,n_B\}$, we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in A\cup B$.